# Problem with 'Speficying custom values in Language Files'

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am working with a Laravel 5.8 version.

I need to modify the output of an error message form, unfortunately, the validation is not working properly.

The documentation says (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation):

---

#### Specifying Custom Values In Language Files

Sometimes you may need the `:value` portion of your validation message to be replaced with a custom representation of the value. For example, consider the following rule that specifies that a credit card number is required if the `payment_type` has a value of `cc`:

```php
$request->validate([
    'credit_card_number' => 'required_if:payment_type,cc'
]);
```

If this validation rule fails, it will produce the following error message:

> The credit card number field is required when payment type is `cc`.

Instead of displaying `cc` as the payment type value, you may specify a custom value representation in your `validation` language file by defining a `values` array:

```php
'values' => [
    'payment_type' => [
        'cc' => 'credit card'
    ],
],
```

Now if the validation rule fails it will produce the following message:

> The credit card number field is required when payment type is `credit card`.

---

I have a validation rule like:

```php
$request->validate([
    'foo' => [
        'required_if:bar.bizz,1',
        'numeric',
    ]
]);
```

And in my `validation.php`.

```php
'values' => [
    'bar.biz' => [
        '1' => 'test',
    ],
    'bar[biz]' => [
        '1' => 'test',
    ],
    '*.*' => [
        '1' => 'test',
    ],
]
```

But I always get the same output:

> The `foo` field is required when `bar` is `1`.

Thanks.

Comment: if you managed to solve the issue post an answer to your question and mark it as solved so that it will be usable for furher reference on the site

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification @LelioFaieta. I need to wait until tomorrow to mark my own response as correct to solve the issue! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved

If you are working in your form with arrays, you have also use arrays like:

```php
'values' => [
    'bar' => [
        'biz' => [
            '1' => 'test',
        ]
    ]
],
```

> Also, note we are not using *`foo`* variable in the `values` array.

PS: The wildcard symbol (`*`)  does not work.

Greetings.